# Cannot copy & paste files from Intellij on mac

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, finder

For a long time I cannot copy&paste files from IntelliJ Idea to Finder. Interesting is that it works the other way I can copy file in Finder and past it in IntelliJ project window. When I copy file in project window in IntelliJ and then try to paste it in Finder, there is the error sound like my clipboard is empty.

Couldn't find solution anywhere. I don't use any third party app for copy&pasting on my mac. The problem was on mac os 10.12 and is still the same on 10.13 and I already tried to set ide.mac.useNativeClipboard=True in idea.properties, it didn't help me. Not sure if this problem started with mac os or IntelliJ idea update but I think it was the later.

Comment: Please follow the related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-147866

Comment: Ah, so there is no solution now :( Thank you

Comment: Although not perfiect; it does work if you drag&drop the file from intelliJ to finder.

Comment: I know I am using that but drag&drop is painfull especially on mac when u have to wait for 2 windows to popup while u drag it, it takes ages or resize the windows